# Embeded Google slides opens new tab on screen touch (mobile mode)

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-slides

I am trying to visualise a google slide presentation embeded in an iframe.
This I frame is suppose to be running on a touchscreen tv, which means on touch (click) it will react as a mobile.
It works fine until i try to click to get to the new slide (doesn't work only swiping works) or try to click on a link to another slide, it opens in a new tab

In mobile mode in a browser I tried checking what i could change but didn't find a solution:

here is a link where it is possible to test:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTSore85AtLqqaA8OFC9mO90IdJ_zCPsC6FFmbRztzNM9ekxe-BrOVYEPXlmQLWgHigEy6A83cx7x2D/embed?slide=id.gcb9a0b074_1_0

Expected outcome is: not opening a new tab when clicking on the "test" button on the first slide but skipping to the 6th slide

Thanks